# Is updating properties of value by index in ConcurrentDictionary thread-safe?

Tags: c#

```
public class Foo 
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class FooHandler 
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Foo> FooHash = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Foo>();

    public IncrementFoo(string key) 
    {
        FooHash[key].Count++;
    }
}
```

Can I update properties of Foo entry in such manner? Is it thread-safe (i.e. are get or set of indexer atomic in this scenario)?

Comment: ConcurrentDirectory is thread-safe, that does not make your Foo class thread-safe.  And it isn't, incrementing a variable is never safe.  You'd need at least Interlocked.Increment() to increment the backing store of the property,  Or lock.

Comment: @HansPassant You can't use `Interlocked` on a property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because you see there is a `ConcurrentDictionary` which contains your objects does not make the objects thread safe. It only makes accessing the objects within the dictionary thread safe, as from msdn:

> Represents a thread-safe collection of key/value pairs that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently.

To make your objects properties access thread safe you would need to lock the code sections inside of them as per:

```
public class Foo
{
    private Object obj;
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            lock (obj)
            {
                //this section is thread safe
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (obj)
            {
                //this section is thread safe
            }
        }
    }
}
```